# increment then decrement radius of arc canvas html5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

hi i am trying to gat an arc to resize as it moves across the screen.
I cant seem to asign the value of increment to the radius of the arc for it to get bigger and then smaller.

please see below for the code block in question and then the entire code.

```
resize(){

            this.up = true;
            this.r = 0;
            this.increment = 10;
            this.ceiling = 100;

            function PerformCalc() {
              if (this.up == true && this.r <= this.ceiling) {
                this.r += increment

                if (this.r == ceiling) {
                  this.up = false;
                }
              } else {
                  this.up = false
                  this.r -= increment;

                  if (this.r == 0) {
                    this.up = true;
                  }
              }
              console.log(this.r);
            }
            setInterval(PerformCalc, 1000);

        }
```

When i log out the radius to the console it gives nan for some reason.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <html>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Canvas</title>
    
        <style type="text/css">
      canvas {
       border: 1px solid grey; 
      }
        </style>
    
      </head>
    
      <body>
    
        <canvas id="canvas-for-ball"></canvas>
    
        <script type="text/javascript">
      // Gets a handle to the element with id canvasOne.
      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas-for-ball");
      // Get a 2D context for the canvas.
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      function init(){
                canvas.width = 500;
                canvas.height = 500;
       
            }
            init();
            //angle defining spin and sections of ball
      var theta = 0;
      //for the sections of the ball
      var theta2 = 0;
      //fort he amount of sections needed
      var seventh = (Math.PI*2)/7
      //to control the amount of spin the ball has
      var thetaInc = 0.0029;
            //ball object
      class Ball {
       constructor(x,y,r,xvel,yvel,mass){
        this.x =x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r =r;
        this.xvel = xvel;
        this.yvel = yvel;
                    this.mass = mass;
       }
                draw(){
        // Update the y location.
        this.x = this.x + this.xvel;
        this.y = this.y + this.yvel;
        //draw circle
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.r,0,Math.PI*2,false);
        ctx.stroke();
        //fill the circle
        ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
        ctx.fill();
        //draw inner circle of ball
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.r*.9,0,Math.PI*2,false);
        ctx.stroke();
        //spin control
        theta += thetaInc;
        //loop for adding sections to pie
        for( var n = 0; n < 7; ++n) {  // add loop to draw radii
         theta2 = theta + n * seventh;
         ctx.moveTo( this.x, this.y);
         ctx.lineTo( this.x + this.r*Math.cos(theta2), this.y + this.r*Math.sin(theta2));
         }
        ctx.lineWidth = "2";
        ctx.lineCap = "round";
        ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
        ctx.stroke();   
       }
                move(){ 
        //condition take into account the this.r of the ball so 
        //it bounces at the edge of the canvas instead 
        //of going off of the screen to its center point.
        if(this.y > canvas.height - this.r || this.y - this.r <0){
         this.yvel = -1*this.yvel;
         //to reverse the direction of the ball when hitting walls
         if((this.xvel<0 && this.yvel >0) && thetaInc <0){
          thetaInc = -1*thetaInc;
         }
         else if((this.xvel <0 && this.yvel>0) && thetaInc >0){
          thetaInc = -1*thetaInc
         }
         else if((this.xvel >0 && this.yvel >0) && thetaInc >0){
          thetaInc = -1 * thetaInc;
         }
         else if((this.xvel > 0 && this.yvel < 0)&& thetaInc <0){
          thetaInc = -1 * thetaInc;
         }
        }
        if(this.x > canvas.width - this.r || this.x - this.r < 0){
         this.xvel = -1*this.xvel;
        }      
       }
       resize(){
        
        this.up = true;
        this.r = 0;
        this.increment = 10;
        this.ceiling = 100;
        
        function PerformCalc() {
          if (this.up == true && this.r <= this.ceiling) {
         this.r += increment
        
         if (this.r == ceiling) {
           this.up = false;
         }
          } else {
           this.up = false
           this.r -= increment;
        
           if (this.r == 0) {
          this.up = true;
           }
          }
          console.log(this.r);
        }
        setInterval(PerformCalc, 1000);
          
         }
    
        
          
         
       colour(){
    
       }
                
    
            }
       
       //Intersect function takes a ball as a perameter
       //ball will be the the object used to test if the two are touching.
       
       function intersect(ball,ball1) {
       //the x and y cordinates of the first ball are subtracted from the test ball and stored
       //in productX and productY
          var productX = ball1.x - ball.x;
          var productY = ball1.y - ball.y;
       //pythagoras theorem is used to get the distance between both center points of each circle.
          var distance = Math.sqrt(productX * productX + productY * productY);
       //A condition is used to check if the distance between both bencer point of each circle
       //is less than or equal to the sum of both radii the circles are touching.
       //the result is p[rinted out to the console
          if (distance <= (ball1.r + ball.r)) {
            
                  dx = ball.x-ball1.x;
                  dy = ball.y-ball1.y;
                  collision_angle = Math.atan2(dy,dx);
                  magnitude_1 = Math.sqrt(ball.xvel*ball.xvel+ball.yvel*ball.yvel);
                  magnitude_2 = Math.sqrt(ball1.xvel*ball1.xvel+ball1.yvel*ball1.yvel);
    
                  direction_1 = Math.atan2(ball.yvel, ball.xvel);
                  direction_2 = Math.atan2(ball1.yvel, ball1.xvel);
    
                  new_xvel_1 = magnitude_1 * Math.cos(direction_1-collision_angle);
                  new_yvel_1 = magnitude_1 * Math.sin(direction_1-collision_angle);
                  new_xvel_2 = magnitude_2 * Math.cos(direction_2-collision_angle);
                  new_yvel_2 = magnitude_1 * Math.sin(direction_2-collision_angle);
    
                  final_xvel_1 = ((ball.mass-ball1.mass)*new_xvel_1+(ball1.mass+ball1.mass)*new_xvel_2)/(ball.mass+ball1.mass);
                  final_xvel_2 = ((ball.mass+ball.mass)*new_xvel_1+(ball1.mass-ball.mass)*new_xvel_2)/(ball.mass+ball1.mass);
    
                  final_yvel_1 = new_yvel_1;
                  final_yvel_2 = new_yvel_2;
    
                  ball.xvel = Math.cos(collision_angle)*final_xvel_1+Math.cos(collision_angle+Math.PI/2)*final_yvel_1;
                  ball.yvel = Math.sin(collision_angle)*final_xvel_1+Math.sin(collision_angle+Math.PI/2)*final_yvel_1;
                  ball1.xvel = Math.cos(collision_angle)*final_xvel_2+Math.cos(collision_angle+Math.PI/2)*final_yvel_2;
                  ball1.yvel = Math.sin(collision_angle)*final_xvel_2+Math.sin(collision_angle+Math.PI/2)*final_yvel_2;
                } 
        }
        canvas.addEventListener("click", function(event) { 
         var clickX = event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
         var clickY = event.clientY- canvas.offsetTop;
         b1.x = clickX;
         b1.y = clickY;  
        });
      // Add a Javascript event listener to the keypress event.
      window.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) { 
       // Just log the event to the console.
       console.log(event);
      });
    
      //keypresses with jQuery
      $(document.body).on('keydown', function(e) {
       console.log(e.which);
       switch (e.which) {
        // key code for left arrow
        case 37:
        console.log('left arrow key pressed!');
        b1.xvel --;
        break;
        //keycode for up
        case 38:
        console.log('up key pressed');
        b1.yvel++;
        break;
        //key code for right
        case 39:
        console.log('right arrow key pressed!');
        b1.xvel++;
        break;
        //key code for down
        case 40:
        console.log('down arrow key pressed!');
        b1.yvel--;
        break;
        //key code for + key to increase spin
        case 107:
        console.log('down arrow key pressed!');
        thetaInc +=.001;
        break;
        //key code for - key to decrease spin
        case 109:
        console.log('down arrow key pressed!');
        thetaInc -=.001;
        break;
       }
      });
     b1 = new Ball(200,200,40,1,1,50);
        b2 = new Ball(100,100,40,2,2,5);
     b1.resize();
        // A function to repeat every time the animation loops.
     function repeatme() {
      //clear canvas for each frame of the animation.
      ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500);
      // Draw the ball (stroked, not filled).
      b1.draw();
            b2.draw();
            b1.move();
      
            b2.move();
            intersect(b1,b2);
      //put repeatme function into the animation frame and store it in animate
      animate =  window.requestAnimationFrame(repeatme); 
     }
         // Get the animation going.
     repeatme();
       
        </script>
    
      </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: increment is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

There is a reference error for increment, e.g. you didn't use this.increment, same for ceiling, should be this.ceiling.

this is used by the setInterval so you save this as that so you can use them. this removes the NaN.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <html>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Canvas</title>
    
        <style type="text/css">
      canvas {
       border: 1px solid grey; 
      }
        </style>
    
      </head>
    
      <body>
    
        <canvas id="canvas-for-ball"></canvas>
    
        <script type="text/javascript">
      // Gets a handle to the element with id canvasOne.
      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas-for-ball");
      // Get a 2D context for the canvas.
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      function init(){
                canvas.width = 500;
                canvas.height = 500;
       
            }
            init();
            //angle defining spin and sections of ball
      var theta = 0;
      //for the sections of the ball
      var theta2 = 0;
      //fort he amount of sections needed
      var seventh = (Math.PI*2)/7
      //to control the amount of spin the ball has
      var thetaInc = 0.0029;
            //ball object
      class Ball {
       constructor(x,y,r,xvel,yvel,mass){
        this.x =x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r =r;
        this.xvel = xvel;
        this.yvel = yvel;
                    this.mass = mass;
       }
                draw(){
        // Update the y location.
        this.x = this.x + this.xvel;
        this.y = this.y + this.yvel;
        //draw circle
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.r,0,Math.PI*2,false);
        ctx.stroke();
        //fill the circle
        ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
        ctx.fill();
        //draw inner circle of ball
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.r*.9,0,Math.PI*2,false);
        ctx.stroke();
        //spin control
        theta += thetaInc;
        //loop for adding sections to pie
        for( var n = 0; n < 7; ++n) {  // add loop to draw radii
         theta2 = theta + n * seventh;
         ctx.moveTo( this.x, this.y);
         ctx.lineTo( this.x + this.r*Math.cos(theta2), this.y + this.r*Math.sin(theta2));
         }
        ctx.lineWidth = "2";
        ctx.lineCap = "round";
        ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
        ctx.stroke();   
       }
                move(){ 
        //condition take into account the this.r of the ball so 
        //it bounces at the edge of the canvas instead 
        //of going off of the screen to its center point.
        if(this.y > canvas.height - this.r || this.y - this.r <0){
         this.yvel = -1*this.yvel;
         //to reverse the direction of the ball when hitting walls
         if((this.xvel<0 && this.yvel >0) && thetaInc <0){
          thetaInc = -1*thetaInc;
         }
         else if((this.xvel <0 && this.yvel>0) && thetaInc >0){
          thetaInc = -1*thetaInc
         }
         else if((this.xvel >0 && this.yvel >0) && thetaInc >0){
          thetaInc = -1 * thetaInc;
         }
         else if((this.xvel > 0 && this.yvel < 0)&& thetaInc <0){
          thetaInc = -1 * thetaInc;
         }
        }
        if(this.x > canvas.width - this.r || this.x - this.r < 0){
         this.xvel = -1*this.xvel;
        }      
       }
       resize(){
        var that = this;
        that.up = true;
        that.r = 0;
        that.increment = 10;
        that.ceiling = 100;
        function PerformCalc() {
          if (that.up == true && that.r <= that.ceiling) {
         that.r += that.increment
        
         if (that.r == that.ceiling) {
           that.up = false;
         }
          } else {
           that.up = false
           that.r -= that.increment;
        
           if (that.r == 0) {
          that.up = true;
           }
          }
          console.log(that.r);
        }
        setInterval(PerformCalc, 1000);
          
         }
    
        
          
         
       colour(){
    
       }
                
    
            }
       
       //Intersect function takes a ball as a perameter
       //ball will be the the object used to test if the two are touching.
       
       function intersect(ball,ball1) {
       //the x and y cordinates of the first ball are subtracted from the test ball and stored
       //in productX and productY
          var productX = ball1.x - ball.x;
          var productY = ball1.y - ball.y;
       //pythagoras theorem is used to get the distance between both center points of each circle.
          var distance = Math.sqrt(productX * productX + productY * productY);
       //A condition is used to check if the distance between both bencer point of each circle
       //is less than or equal to the sum of both radii the circles are touching.
       //the result is p[rinted out to the console
          if (distance <= (ball1.r + ball.r)) {
            
                  dx = ball.x-ball1.x;
                  dy = ball.y-ball1.y;
                  collision_angle = Math.atan2(dy,dx);
                  magnitude_1 = Math.sqrt(ball.xvel*ball.xvel+ball.yvel*ball.yvel);
                  magnitude_2 = Math.sqrt(ball1.xvel*ball1.xvel+ball1.yvel*ball1.yvel);
    
                  direction_1 = Math.atan2(ball.yvel, ball.xvel);
                  direction_2 = Math.atan2(ball1.yvel, ball1.xvel);
    
                  new_xvel_1 = magnitude_1 * Math.cos(direction_1-collision_angle);
                  new_yvel_1 = magnitude_1 * Math.sin(direction_1-collision_angle);
                  new_xvel_2 = magnitude_2 * Math.cos(direction_2-collision_angle);
                  new_yvel_2 = magnitude_1 * Math.sin(direction_2-collision_angle);
    
                  final_xvel_1 = ((ball.mass-ball1.mass)*new_xvel_1+(ball1.mass+ball1.mass)*new_xvel_2)/(ball.mass+ball1.mass);
                  final_xvel_2 = ((ball.mass+ball.mass)*new_xvel_1+(ball1.mass-ball.mass)*new_xvel_2)/(ball.mass+ball1.mass);
    
                  final_yvel_1 = new_yvel_1;
                  final_yvel_2 = new_yvel_2;
    
                  ball.xvel = Math.cos(collision_angle)*final_xvel_1+Math.cos(collision_angle+Math.PI/2)*final_yvel_1;
                  ball.yvel = Math.sin(collision_angle)*final_xvel_1+Math.sin(collision_angle+Math.PI/2)*final_yvel_1;
                  ball1.xvel = Math.cos(collision_angle)*final_xvel_2+Math.cos(collision_angle+Math.PI/2)*final_yvel_2;
                  ball1.yvel = Math.sin(collision_angle)*final_xvel_2+Math.sin(collision_angle+Math.PI/2)*final_yvel_2;
                } 
        }
        canvas.addEventListener("click", function(event) { 
         var clickX = event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
         var clickY = event.clientY- canvas.offsetTop;
         b1.x = clickX;
         b1.y = clickY;  
        });
      // Add a Javascript event listener to the keypress event.
      window.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) { 
       // Just log the event to the console.
       console.log(event);
      });
    
      //keypresses with jQuery
      $(document.body).on('keydown', function(e) {
       console.log(e.which);
       switch (e.which) {
        // key code for left arrow
        case 37:
        console.log('left arrow key pressed!');
        b1.xvel --;
        break;
        //keycode for up
        case 38:
        console.log('up key pressed');
        b1.yvel++;
        break;
        //key code for right
        case 39:
        console.log('right arrow key pressed!');
        b1.xvel++;
        break;
        //key code for down
        case 40:
        console.log('down arrow key pressed!');
        b1.yvel--;
        break;
        //key code for + key to increase spin
        case 107:
        console.log('down arrow key pressed!');
        thetaInc +=.001;
        break;
        //key code for - key to decrease spin
        case 109:
        console.log('down arrow key pressed!');
        thetaInc -=.001;
        break;
       }
      });
     b1 = new Ball(200,200,40,1,1,50);
        b2 = new Ball(100,100,40,2,2,5);
     b1.resize();
        // A function to repeat every time the animation loops.
     function repeatme() {
      //clear canvas for each frame of the animation.
      ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500);
      // Draw the ball (stroked, not filled).
      b1.draw();
            b2.draw();
            b1.move();
      
            b2.move();
            intersect(b1,b2);
      //put repeatme function into the animation frame and store it in animate
      animate =  window.requestAnimationFrame(repeatme); 
     }
         // Get the animation going.
     repeatme();
       
        </script>
    
      </body>
    
    </html>
```